# how to get found rows while executing a query with limit in mysqli?

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli, datatable

I am using jquery datatable with a serverside pagination (php rest server)
and i have to get the full count when i execute a query with limit

After searching, I found that i can use FOUND_ROWS() but it won't work for me
here's the code

```
$sql = "select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * from `products`".($key?" WHERE id=$key":'')." ORDER BY ".$cols[$_GET['order'][0]['column']]." ".$_GET['order'][0]['dir']." LIMIT ".$_GET['start']." ,".$_GET['length'];

$sql2="SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as countall";

$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

$result2 = mysqli_query($link,$sql2);

$count= mysqli_fetch_object($result2);

var_dump( $count->countall); 

$data = array();

for ($i=0;$i<mysqli_num_rows($result);$i++) {

    $data[$i]= mysqli_fetch_object($result);

 }
```

Is there any mistake i made ?
I want just return the countall value

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change `mysqli_fetch_object` into `mysqli_fetch_assoc`